# Hazelcast MapLoader taking time to load the data from Hbase

Tags: java, hbase, hazelcast

We are using Hazelcast as our cached database in our project and HBase as the persistent database solution. We load the data from Hbase to Hazelcast using MapLoader when the application starts. Below is the snippet of the loadAll() function.

```
@Override
public synchronized Map<String, Object> loadAll(Collection<String> rows) {
    final Map<String, Object> mapObject = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    try {
        if (!rows.isEmpty()) {
            //Get Scanner from Hbase
            final ResultScanner scanner = loadAllData(rows, this.mapName);
            final byte[] family = this.mapName.getBytes();
            final byte[] qualifier = this.mapName.getBytes();
            //Load data from Hbase to Hazelcast
            for (Result result = scanner.next(); result != null; result = scanner
                    .next()) {
                mapObject
                        .put(Bytes.toString(result.getRow()),
                                convertToObject(result.getValue(family,
                                        qualifier)));
            }
            LOGGER.logDebug(Constants.EXIT, methodName,
                    "All the data's are successfully loaded for Table "
                            + this.mapName);
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return mapObject;
}
```

We have a table with 350k entries (total data size of 300 mb) and its taking close to 1.5 hour to load the data. Is this normal behavior? Does Hazelcast usually take this much time to load the data?

Comment: How long does the load take outside of Hazelcast? What is your heapsize? How are objects serialized? What does this "convertToObject" do? Every answer at the current point in time would be a "wild guess" :) Especially the first counter-question is the most interesting one.

Comment: PS: How many nodes do you use? Guess you're not running single node, embedded? And what's the Hazelcast version?

Comment: @noctarius - We don't know how much time does it take outside. I've been constantly monitoring it on mancenter(memory, CPU seems fine)  Heap size is 6GB/8GB. Function "convertToObject()"  will use the SerializationUtil's "deserialize" function to deserialize the data before loading it in Hazelcast. 
We are using a multinode setup with 3 nodes in the cluster.Current Hazelcast version is 3.6.5

Comment: What means 6GB/8GB? 6GB free of a 8GB heap?

Comment: No it means -Xms 6GB and -Xmx 8GB. Our heap usage is somewhere between 2GB - 3GB

Comment: Ah ok, I would suggest to try to read the information outside of Hazelcast first, to make sure it is somewhere related to the MapLoader.

Comment: @HusainTopiwala, were you able to get the time taken outside of HZ? or else, you can have some kind of timer inside that loop, break the put & object creation operations and check the timetaken for those especially the `convertToObject()`.

Comment: If you are able to upgrade to Hazelcast 3.8, you will be able to use the diagnostics for MapLoaders added in this version. See http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#diagnostics on how to enable diagnostics and the StoreLatency plugin. Apart from that, I observe your MapLoader is synchronized: if this means you need exclusive access to a resource in your implementation, then this may cause delays or even deadlock; try to use a more granular exclusive access approach. If you need exclusive access across all your nodes, consider Hazelcast's ILock.